# Can I use an IF statement in an HTACCESS so that I can 301 redirect only specific domain (for multidomains on single docroot)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, if-statement, redirect

I run a server with a cloud/webservice and my users can access their accounts through their subdomains:

- my main site: [www.myservice.com](http://www.myservice.com)
- user A: usera.myservice.com
- user B: userb.myservice.com

Recently I added the option for users to use their own domain. This works great through a virtual server. So now if someone visits [www.usera.com](http://www.usera.com), they see "www.usera.com" in the browser, but in fact they use usera.myservice.com ("multidomains on single docroot" I think this is called)

So far so good.

My problem is: User A already has a site and would like to have permanent redirects to have old URLs pointing to the new.
But when I implement this in the htaccess that is in the rootfolder, then the rules apply to ALL domains, including myservice.com.

**I would like to implement 301 redirect, but only for chosen domains.**

I think I am close, but... this doesnt work.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^usera.com\./">
   Redirect 301 /oldpath/product1 https://usera.com/newpath/product1
   Redirect 301 /newsartciles/article1 https://usera.com/read/article1
   //etc
</If>
```

So: IF the HTTP_HOST contains 'usera.com' (with 'wildcard' in front and in back of 'usera.com'), then (and only then) apply all 376 redirect 301 rules within that IF statement.

Can anyone help me out? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your regular expression is demanding a dot at the end of the host name, but the host name is not really `usera.com.`

Comment: (And for the first dot in that expression, the escaping is missing.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! 
I am a total noob in regex (as you can tell), but I would like to learn. Could you tell me how it should have been written for it to work?
Like this?
**<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^usera\.com.\./">**

Comment: `/^usera\.com$/` - the dot is meant to be a literal dot and not a wildcard character, so it needs to be escaped. And you don’t want to find anything else after the `…com` - so no more dots and escaped dots there, but simply a dollar sign, to anchor the pattern to the end there, same as `^` did at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind!
I found that I **did not have to use any wildcard**. The following works perfectly, in my situation:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'usera.com'">
   Redirect 301 /oldpath/product1 https://usera.com/newpath/product1
   Redirect 301 /newsartciles/article1 https://usera.com/read/article1
   //etc
</If>
```

I implement this if statement, **after** some http->https and www->non-www rules:

```
#first: www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#then: force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

#and then
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'usera.com'">
   Redirect 301 /oldpath/product1 https://usera.com/newpath/product1
   Redirect 301 /newsartciles/article1 https://usera.com/read/article1
   //etc
</If>
```

And with this, I have it working like I hoped.